# read TypedChoiceField data from form

Tags: django

I have a `FormView` which takes in a `ModelForm`. The model has `SmallIntegerField`.

In my `FormView`, I am trying to read the data using the Forms API.
However, this is not working

```
status = int(form.fields['status'])
```

I get,

```
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'TypedChoiceField'
```

Answer (score 3):

As the error suggests, `form.fields['status']` is the field itself, not the value of the field.

You can access the value of the field with `form.cleaned_data['status']`. If you are using `TypedChoiceField` then you shouldn't have to convert to an integer, since the field will do this for you.